# MTLTextureDescriptor error when loading spritekit scene

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, metal

I have "MTLTextureDescriptor has one or more dimensions set that are zero or greater than the maximum allowed size" error when loading my spritekit game on iPad. When I load it in simulator there's no error. Anyone can help?

Comment: Fixed this – had an extra uiview

Comment: I am seeing the same error. Could you please describe in more details what caused the problem in your case? BTW, you can answer your own question and get a badge if it helps somebody.